# ES6 Classes that depend on each other in static variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6, ecma

I have two classes that I want to define relationships for.  I am trying to use static variables to achieve this however the references to the classes are not defined.

```
import BaseQuery from "../../src/BaseQuery";
import Checklist from "./Checklist";

export default class Task extends BaseQuery {
  static belongsTo = [Checklist];
}
```

---

```
import BaseQuery from "../../src/BaseQuery";
import Task from "./Task";

export default class Checklist extends BaseQuery {
  static hasMany = [Task];
}
```

In the Task class, checklist is undefined and in the Checklist class Task is defined but not as I would expect it. Is there anyway to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just experienced circular dependency. `Task` needs `Checklist` and `Checklist` needs `Task`; the interpretor cannot deal with that.

One of the soluce would be to use the [get operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fonctions/get), which will delay the resolution of `Checklist` and `Task` classes and fix the circular dependency issue.

`Checklist` and `Task` gotta be resolved by the interpretor when calling `belongsTo`/`hasMany`.

---

**Working example** :

```js
class Task {
  static get belongsTo() {
    return [Checklist];
  }

  static get name() {
    return 'Task-class';
  }
}

class Checklist {
  static get hasMany() {
    return [Task];
  }

  static get name() {
    return 'Checklist-task';
  }
}

console.log(Checklist.hasMany.map(x => x.name));

console.log(Task.belongsTo.map(x => x.name));
```

Comment: Notice that the static class fields from the OPs code wouldn't even work if the two `class` declarations were in the same file

Comment: @Bergi yes you are right, thanks. I've updated my answer with a snippet giving more explanation about a working soluce.

Comment: Now that you have used getters (which is a solution on its own), there's no need to put them in the same file any more.

Comment: @Bergi Hm I though that the dependency would still be a problem using import. But after what you have said, I have created a mini-project of my own and you are 100% right. The interpretor do not need to resolve at import time when using getter. Thx, I've learned something

Comment: The export just needs to be declared to be resolvable, it doesn't need to be initialised yet. It's like hoisting across modules.

Comment: I have not verified that this works with the exports yet but thank you both.  Now I am trying to get access to it from a static method on base Query. :/ That looks like it will need to be a separate question though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it from inside the class (as whichever you define first wouldn't know about the second, and it would also probably require static constructors).  However, I was able to get it to work with static methods called after the classes themselves are defined:

```
class Rubyish{
    static appendProp(propName, value){
        if (!this[propName]) {
            this[propName] = []
        }
        this[propName].push(value)
    }
    static belongsTo(cls){
        this.appendProp('belongsToClasses', cls)
    }
    static hasMany(cls){
        this.appendProp('hasManyClasses', cls)
    }
}

class Task extends Rubyish{
}

class Checklist extends Rubyish{
}

Task.belongsTo(Checklist)
Checklist.hasMany(Task)
```

*Edit to add:* This may have been overkill, as you could do it without static methods:

```
class NewTask{}
class NewCheckList{}

NewTask.belongsTo = [NewCheckList]

NewCheckList.hasMany = [NewTask]
```